# AZRE SQL / SQL server write back to Azure storage by T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way I can write file to azure storage from AZRE SQL .

Please note : I have created secure connection and able to read file from storage to SQL server . But not able to write back  to the file .

Any suggestion . Below code using to write on premise file but not sure for Azure SQL

```sql
declare @fn varchar(500) = 'E:/c/logs/'+@filename+'_'+@fileTimeStamp+'.'+@fileExtension;
    declare @cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', @var, ' > "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output

  
    set @cmd  = concat('type "', @fn, '"');

    print @cmd 
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the architecture of your database, the only solution I'm aware of is running [CETAS statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas) when in a server pool (using Synapse).

Otherwise, you are looking at Data Factory or SSIS with the Azure toolkit.